# como modificar layout en android estudio

Tags: android, android-studio

Hola amigos como puedo modificar el layout o mainactivity en android estudio ya que cuando instalo la aplicacion la barra azul me roba, el total del top en la pantalla y me gustaría que asumiera la pantalla completa

Alguna sugerencia

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Supongo que quieres que la actividad ocupa la pantalla completa, no la toolbar?

Comment: es correcto, alguna sugerencia

Comment: @AlexanderQuiroz en realidad lo que se debe realizar es eliminar el Toolbar, ya que estableciendo match_parent no es suficiente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que no sea mostrado el Toolbar debes definir el siguiente tema dentro del archivo Styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

y en la definicion de tu Activity agregas el tema, por ejemplo:

```
  <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
```

De esta forma tendras tu aplicación sin el Toolbar (ActionBar).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Deberias modificar ciertos parametros en el layout de ese activity. Debes buscar el elemento que representa a toolbar y cambiar el valor de su propiedad height a match-parent

Comment: Gracias Sonia Hice la modificación que me sugeriste peo aun así me sigue apareciendo creo que mas bien debe ser lo del layout , no soy muy experto con android pero por el código noto que estoy dentro del layout y necesito que sea totalmente en blanco para que el webview me asuma todo el tamaño

Comment: Y porque se necesita una toolbar de pantalla completa?

Comment: lo que sucede es que estoy haciendo un webview y al instalar la app me deja la barra azul arriba sin ninguna utilidad y me toma tamaño de la aplicacion web

Comment: Entonces necesitas de hacer la AppBar desaparecer y tener la WebView pantalla completa. Podrías dejarlo más claro, o te podrían llegar más respuestas como tener tu AppBar en pantalla completa ;)

Answer (score 0):

Tu puedes cambiar el tema para tu actividad (sin cambiar el tema general) en la siguiente forma:

```
<activity android:name=".MiActividadSinAppBar"
      android:label="@string/mi_app"
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
```

Para tu `MainActivity` entonces:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:label="@string/mi_app"
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
```

Para definir un estilo con tema propia sin AppBar, colocas lo siguiente en tu `values/styles.xml`:

false
        true

y en tu layout:

```
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```